# Why doesn't 2.__add__(3) work in Python?

Tags: python, methods, int, syntax-error

The integer `2` has an `__add__` method:

```
>>> "__add__" in dir(2)
True
```

... but calling it raises a SyntaxError:

```
>>> 2.__add__(3)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    2.__add__(3)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why can't I use the `__add__` method?

Comment: Variants of this theme are relatively common questions around here.  It's quite interesting, although I can't really see any reason why you would want to do this instead of just `2 + 3`.

Comment: @mgilson: `(2).__add__` could serve as an "add by two" function, instead of `lambda x: x+2`.

Comment: @unutbu -- Interesting.  I suppose that would be a clever (less easy to read?) way to do that ... It's a good point though.  I suppose I'll be on the lookout for it in the future!

Comment: @unutbu: I'd rather use `functools.partial(operator.add, 2)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: On what basis do you make that choice?

Comment: @unutbu: `functools.partial()` is a very fast wrapper, no additional frame push is needed as it is implemented in C, and so is `operator.add`; it is faster than the lambda for that. `(2).__add__` also returns the `NotImplemented` singleton instead of raising `TypeError`, when passing in an incompatible type.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for pointing that out. `(2).__add__(3.)` raises `NotImplemented`... not very desireable.

Comment: @unutbu: not raises, **returns**. `result = (2).__add__('3')` means `result` is now bound to the `NotImplemented` singleton.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oops, yes.

Comment: @unutbu: because `int.__add__(float)` returns `NotImplemented`, `float.__radd__(int)` is tried and that succeeds. `functools.partial(operator.add, 2)` takes care of all those details too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`2.` is parsed as a float, so `2.__add__` is a SyntaxError.

You can evaluate

`(2).__add__(3)` instead.

---

```
In [254]: (2).__add__(3)
Out[254]: 5
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to get around `2.` being parsed as a float is to insert a space between the `2` and the `.`

```
>>> 2 .__add__(3)
5
```