# Why is "1.real" a syntax error but "1 .real" valid in Python?

Tags: python

So I saw [these two](https://twitter.com/bmispelon/status/613816239622909953) [questions on twitter](https://twitter.com/bmispelon/status/613818391967715329). How is `1.real` a syntax error but `1 .real` is not?

```
>>> 1.real
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1.real
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 1 .real
1
>>> 1. real
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1. real
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 1 . real
1
>>> 1..real
1.0
>>> 1 ..real
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 ..real
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 1.. real
1.0
>>> 1 .. real
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 .. real
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I guess `1.` is greedily parsed to a float number, and then `real` is missing the `.`, whereas `1 .real` parses `1` as an `int`. Spaces are not allowed around decimal point, but you can have spaces before and after 'method accessor dot' (for lack of a better name).

Comment: This has been asked before, I think repeatedly. I'm having trouble finding the dupes, though.

Comment: Probably one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390458/why-doesnt-2-add-3-work-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255693/attribute-access-on-int-literals

Comment: try: `(1).real` or `1.0.real` or `1..real` (they are all the same)

Comment: There are arguments to change this behavior, but if you make `1.real` an attribute access, then `1.e4` looks like an attribute access, and perfectly fine code that used to produce `10000.0` suddenly produces an AttributeError. It's not worth the hassle. I'm pretty sure Ruby allows this kind of access, since ints have more interesting methods over there; I'm not sure what they do to handle it.

Comment: Possibly also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955703/accessing-a-python-int-literals-methods

Comment: Aside: Please try to avoid clickbait question titles -- that is to say, please try to add enough information that someone can have a reasonable idea of whether a question is interesting or applicable to them *before* they click to open it. I've attempted to edit this to do so here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry about that.

Comment: @user2357112 From brief experimentation, Ruby allows `1.real` by disallowing `1.` as syntax for a floating point number. So `1.e4` can *only* be a call of the `e4` method on `1`.

Comment: Note: the same exact thing happens basically in **most** damn languages. I believe I read exactly the same thing about javascript just the other day. That's simply the way in which float and attribute accesses are parsed by *most* languages out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is python .. ("dot dot") notation syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487811/what-is-python-dot-dot-notation-syntax)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I guess that the `.` is greedily parsed as part of a number, if possible, making it the `float` `1.`, instead of being part of the method call.

Spaces are not allowed around the decimal point, but you can have spaces before and after the `.` in a method call. If the number is followed by a space, the parse of the number is terminated, so it's unambiguous.

Let's look at the different cases and how they are parsed:

```
>>> 1.real    # parsed as (1.)real  -> missing '.'
>>> 1 .real   # parsed as (1).real  -> okay
>>> 1. real   # parsed as (1.)real  -> missing '.'
>>> 1 . real  # parsed as (1).real  -> okay
>>> 1..real   # parsed as (1.).real -> okay
>>> 1 ..real  # parsed as (1)..real -> one '.' too much
>>> 1.. real  # parsed as (1.).real -> okay
>>> 1 .. real # parsed as (1)..real -> one '.' too much
```

Comment: I was tempted to downvote this simply because I don't want to admit that `1..real` is "okay"....+1 though for showing me something (cringe-worthy) that I didn't realize.

Comment: Fun fact: SO's syntax highlighting for this answer is consistent with how Python interprets it. That is, there should be exactly one black dot (as opposed to the reddish dot) between the `1` and the `real`.

Comment: @leewangzhong Well, SO uses google-prettify to perform highlighting and it's well-known that google uses a lot of Python so it's not surprising that the highlighting is actually a good one and not just a naive approximation...

Answer (score 11):

With `1.real` Python is looking for a floating-point numeric literal like `1.0` and you can't have an `r` in a float. With `1 .real` Python has taken `1` as an integer and is doing the attribute lookup on that.

It's important to note that the floating-point syntax error handling happens before the `.` attribute lookup.

Comment: why does `1.real` cause a syntax error if there's a member called `real`?

Comment: `[0-9].[0-9]` is how a float is defined it partially matches and fails you cannot do direct attribute lookups on integers without letting the interpretter somehow know that its an attribute and not a float

Comment: type `dir(int())` you will see many methods ... you cannot access any of them as `1.xxxx` however you can access any of them with `1 .xxxx` or `(1).xxxxx`

Comment: Ahh, because the `.` in the floating point takes precedent over the `.` in attribute lookup.

Comment: yes effectively at least since evaluating the type is a very high precedence operation ... (really I dont think precedence is the way to describe it, however before you can look up attributes, the interpreter must know what its looking up attributes on)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ohhh. So `1.real` is like writing `1. real` which is invalid.

Comment: @JoranBeasley is that `[0-9]+.[0-9]+|.[0-9]+|[0-9]+.`?

Comment: @kindall The point is that most people resolve syntax ambiguities with parentheses. Not with whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

1 .real works because it is the attribute .real called on the integer 1.

1.real does not work, because you imperatively need a space at the end of a float. Otherwise it is a syntax error.

Comment: Spaces aren't needed at the end of literals. `1+2` is fine, `1..real` is fine, et cetera.